# Create unique MultiIndex from Non-unique Index Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with a non-unique index:

```
index = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1': [1,3,7,6,2,4,3,4]}, index=index)

df
Out[12]: 
   col1
1     1
1     3
1     7
1     6
2     2
2     4
2     3
3     4
```

I'd like to turn this into unique MultiIndex and preserve order, like this:

```
        col1
  Ind2      
1 0        1
  1        3
  2        7
  3        6
2 0        2
  1        4
  2        3
3 0        4
```

I would imagine pandas would have a function for something like this but haven't found anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do a [`groupby.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) on the index, and then append it as a new level to the index using [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)
```

The resulting output:

```
     col1
1 0     1
  1     3
  2     7
  3     6
2 0     2
  1     4
  2     3
3 0     4
```